# Custom element.prototype function has undefined "this"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I'm trying to create a back up function which will be used in case the browser doesn't support classList

```
if(!Element.prototype.classList)    {
  Element.prototype.classList = {};

  Element.prototype.classList.contains =
    function(class_name){
        console.log(this)
    }
}
```

The console.log(this) returns "undefined", how do i get the element on which the function was called then?

Comment: https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills#classlist

Answer (score 0):

It may be that IE8's `console.log()` is "breaking" the result somehow. In the console in IE8 compatibility mode (in IE11), this correctly shows `[object Object] { }` as the return value, expandable to show the attached `contains()` function:

```
Element.prototype.classList = {};
Element.prototype.classList.contains = function() {
  return this;
};
var n = document.createElement('div');
n.classList.contains(x);
```

But, wrapping that return value in a `console.log()` shows `undefined`. Simply letting it "flow through" to the console, however, shows the object as expected.

<sub>Possibly related to the ancient IE quirk, wherein `console` doesn't exist unless the developer tools are opened?</sub>